# How To Auto Refresh Xml page in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Trying to auto refresh xml page with timer but i see the node but the timer does not work. I post my code if you can find the problem thanks a lot in advance.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dom As New Xml.XmlDocument
    dom.Load("http://69.175.13.131:8050/stats")
    TextBox1.Clear()
    Dim monitorid As String = String.Empty
    For Each node As Xml.XmlNode In  dom.SelectNodes("//SHOUTCASTSERVER/SONGTITLE")
    monitorid = node.InnerText
    TextBox1.Text=(monitorid)
Next
    Dim timer As New Timer()
    timer.Interval = 20000
    AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf TextBox1.Refresh
    timer.Start()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Control.Refresh` method is only to redraw the control, not update its contents (unless you write code in an unexpected place to do that).

If you put the code to retrieve the data in a separate method, you can make it a bit tidier and easier to see what is happening in the code. Something like:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim tim As Timer

    Sub ShowCurrentSongTitle(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim dom As New Xml.XmlDocument
        dom.Load("http://69.175.13.131:8050/stats")
        Dim node As Xml.XmlNode = dom.SelectSingleNode("//SHOUTCASTSERVER/SONGTITLE")
        Dim monitorid As String = node.InnerText
        TextBox1.Text = monitorid
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = monitorid.Length

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ShowCurrentSongTitle(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)
        tim = New Timer With {.Interval = 20000}
        AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf ShowCurrentSongTitle
        tim.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        ' tidy up...
        RemoveHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf ShowCurrentSongTitle

    End Sub

End Class
```